# VBA getElementsByClassName not returning all elements

Tags: vba, httprequest, loading

I am trying to get all image src attributes from a website. I have managed to find the elements I'm after, but getElementsByClassName() is only returning 12 of the 30+ elements.

It's doing this because on page load, only the first 12 elements are loaded, and you have to scroll down to keep loading the rest of the elements. I have tried waiting for the readystate, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I believe there is a way to scroll to the bottom of the page to load the entire document with IE or Chrome, but I can't find any way to do this without a browser.

Is it possible?

```
Sub GetImageLinks()

    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ListItem As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim ListItems As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim i As Integer
    
    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://www.rizoma.com/en/motorcycle/mirrors.html", False
    XMLReq.send
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While XMLReq.readyState <> 4
    Loop
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    Set XMLReq = Nothing
    
    Set ListItems = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("product-top")
    
    Debug.Print ListItems.Length

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734187/scraping-dynamic-web-page-with-vba-based-on-xmlhttp-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping dynamic web page with VBA based on XMLHTTP object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734187/scraping-dynamic-web-page-with-vba-based-on-xmlhttp-object)

Comment: So in the website, there are 2 images for each product (1 static and 1 upon hover), are you looking to get both src? Each request actually fetches you 12 items so what you can do is pass in the `p` parameter to the URL like so `https://www.rizoma.com/en/motorcycle/mirrors.html?p=1` and after you process the 12 items, + 1 to the `p` parameter and call again for the next 12 items e.g. `https://www.rizoma.com/en/motorcycle/mirrors.html?p=2` for the 2nd page @Schming

Comment: @RaymondWu that worked great. Thank you! I wrapped the entire sub in a for loop and called each page in succession. is the `p` parameter something you saw in the html, or is that something that is applicable to any page with dynamic loading?

Comment: I can't remember if the address bar shows it but this is the XHR request that was called (and you can see it in DevTools) when you reached the end of page and the website loads a new list of items. No, this is not something that is applicable to any page with dynamic loading as there are many ways to do it. However if your intention is to say scrape other categories of rizoma's website, there's a good chance you can apply this method as well. @Schming